# Would IndexedDB load database into RAM for manipulation or keep it on hard disk?

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm developing a Chrome (Dictionary) Extension and using IndexedDB to store the vocabulary database.

When the extension is opened, the database will be populated (through a js file of course) and as I understand it, Chrome stores the data (on hard disk) at:`/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB/<extension>` (I use a Mac).

My question is when I use the extension, will this data be loaded (from hard disk) into RAM for manipulation (like CRUD) or stay on hard disk?

Thank you.

Comment: You're asking about an implementation detail the answer for which is not guaranteed to be constant.